# Trying to hide "Remove Ads" button whilst ads are switched off but not staying hidden

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I have this script that removes ads for 10 minutes if the player has watched a rewarded ad:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int loadCount = 0;
    private static bool noAds = false;
    private static DateTime noAdsTime = new DateTime();

    void Start()
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (noAdsTime != new DateTime())
            noAds = DateTime.Compare(currentTime, noAdsTime) < 0 ? true : false; //DateTime.Compare returns less than zero if currentTime is earlier than noAdsTime.

        if (loadCount % 5 == 0 && noAds == false)  //  show ad every 5th time
        {
            ShowAd();
        }
        loadCount++;
    }


    public void ActivateNoAds(int minutes)
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        noAdsTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minutes);

    }
    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine. And now I am trying to hide the "Remove Ads" button during the 10 mins of no ads. I have tried to copy the structure of the above script to hide the button for 10 mins too... And I can get it to hide but the next time the player lands on game over the button appears again (but the ads are still off). I have tried its own script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class AdsRemoveButton : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static bool noButton = false;
    private static DateTime noButtonTime = new DateTime();


    void Start()
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (noButtonTime != new DateTime())
            noButton = DateTime.Compare(currentTime, noButtonTime) < 0 ? true : false; //DateTime.Compare returns less than zero if currentTime is earlier than noAdsTime.
    }

    public void ActivateNoButton(int minutes)
    {

        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        noButtonTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minutes);
        GameObject.Find("Remove Ads Button").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // Hide button


    }
```

And a combined script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int loadCount = 0;
    private static bool noAds = false;
    private static DateTime noAdsTime = new DateTime();
    private static bool noButton = false;
    private static DateTime noButtonTime = new DateTime();

    void Start()
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (noAdsTime != new DateTime())
            noAds = DateTime.Compare(currentTime, noAdsTime) < 0 ? true : false; //DateTime.Compare returns less than zero if currentTime is earlier than noAdsTime.

        if (noButtonTime != new DateTime())
            noButton = DateTime.Compare(currentTime, noButtonTime) < 0 ? true : false; //DateTime.Compare returns less than zero if currentTime is earlier than noAdsTime.

        if (loadCount % 5 == 0 && noAds == false)  //  show ad every 5th time
        {
            ShowAd();
        }
        loadCount++;
    }


    public void ActivateNoAds(int minutes)
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        noAdsTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minutes);


    }

    public void ActivateNoButton(int minutes)
    {

        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        noButtonTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minutes);
        GameObject.Find("Remove Ads Button").transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // Hide button


    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Please forgive my probably dumb mistake. I am very much a beginner.

I am assigning these to the button's On Click and getting no errors so I don't know why it is not working? The

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks!